Turn off auto hash generation in Artifactory OSS
I use Artifactory OSS with a remote repository. When I download a file someFileName.jar.sha256, Artifactory delivers it although there is no such .sha256 file cached. And the mirrored remote repository doesn't provide it either.
So far as I understand Artifactory generates it automatically (it seems to do it for md5 and sha256, but not for sha512). Even though I set the checksum policy to "Ignore and pass-through". How can I turn off this automatic generation?
